# Why doesnt my ruby coding for finding prime numbers work?

Tags: ruby, algorithm, primes

I am wondering why my code does not work. I am new to the code world so if anyone can break this problem down for me and how would be best to solve it thanks!

I am trying to create a program which will indicate the prime numbers from a list of numbers that I specify.

Please tell my why these two codes do not work! I am confused as to what the second code is trying to do as I found it as someone else's solution to my problem. I am new to coding but I love it so bear with me!

Here is my simple code:

```
def is_prime?(*nums)

    i = 2
    nums.each do |num|
        while i < num
            if num % i == 0
                puts "#{num} is not a prime"
            else
                puts "#{num} is a prime"
            end
            i += 1
        end
    end
end
```

....Why does this not work? How can I get it to work? It keeps giving me a weird answer in that it gets stuck on my first number and doesnt seem to process the next numbers I insert when I put:

```
puts is_prime?(21, 23, 17)
```

Here is a second code that I wasnt able to run correctly either. Can someone break down what is going on here? How can I get it to work?

```
def is_prime?(*nums)
    nums.each_with_object({}) do |num, hsh|
        hsh[num] = num > 1 && 2.upto(num - 1).none? {|i| num % i == 0}
    end
end

puts is_prime?(27, 13, 42)
```

Anyways, I know this question is kind of confusing but if anyone cares to input their 2 cents I would appreciate it! Oh and lastly how do I post code on question board this correctly? I am so new and so confused without a mentor!

Comment: (num % i) != 0 does not imply that `num` is prime, only that that particular trial divisor `i` is not a factor.

Comment: you can revisit answers, I provided optimised version of algorithm below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few problems. One was identified earlier: the location of the statement `i = 2`. Here is your code with that fixed.

```
def is_prime?(*nums)
    nums.each do |num|
    i = 2
      while i < num
        if num % i == 0
          puts "#{num} is not a prime"
        else
          puts "#{num} is a prime"
        end
        i += 1
      end
   end
end
```

When `num % i == 0` you've determined the number is not prime, and print a message to that effect, but then you continue checking to see if it is divisible all larger numbers less than `num`.  Each time `num % i == 0` you print out that it's not prime.  The point is that you don't need to keep checking once you determine a number is not prime.

Another problem is whenever `num % i != 0` you print that the number is prime.  That's premature, however.  You can't draw that conclusion until you determine that `num % i != 0` for all integers less than `num`.

Let's see how to fix these problems. I think the easiest ways is to write a separate method that determines if a single number is prime.  I've called that method `is_prime?` and renamed the main method `is_each_prime?`.

```
def is_each_prime?(*nums)
  nums.each { |num|
    puts "#{num} is #{ is_prime?(num) ? '' : "not " }a prime" }
end

def is_prime?(num)
  (2...Math.sqrt(num)).all? { |i| num % i != 0 }
end

puts is_each_prime?(21, 23, 17)
  #=> 21 is not a prime
  #   23 is a prime
  #   17 is a prime
```

One advantage of creating a separate method `is_prime?` is that you can test it separately, to make sure it is working properly.

Comment: @NormanKang why to iterate through even numbers and secondly why to continue once *i > num / 2* ? Check your algorithm on bigger number to get same result with double time over optimised algorithm.

Comment: @Norman, I wrote that when I was just a kid and you know what kids are like. I've edited it. Yes, it would be faster to skip multiples of `2` (unless `num = 2`, which is prime), but would be even faster to skip multiples of `3` as well.

Comment: @Anatoly, my comment above was meant mainly for you.

Answer (score 12):

Prime numbers exclude evens (except 2 of course), so you can skip them in outer and inner loops. Once you found out number is prime, break the loop. Two those techniques speed up algorithm dramatically, with my experiments from 3.9sec downto 0.2sec on 10000 array.

Standard inneficient algorithm first:

```
class PrimeNumbers

  def initialize(size)
    @array = (2..size).to_a
    @prime = []
    raise ArgumentError if size < 2
  end

  def process
    @array.each do |i|
      @prime.push(i) if inner_loop(i)
    end
    @prime
  end

  private

  def inner_loop(e)
    is_prime = true
    e.downto(2) do |k|
      next if k == e
      if e % k == 0
        is_prime = false
        break
      end
    end
    is_prime
  end

end
```

Next step is to ask these questions:

1. Where to skip even numbers?
2. why to even iterate through even numbers?
3. why to iterate beyond a certain point?
4. Is there any chance to have prime number once you pass half of array?

So let's see 30x faster algorithm (input 50000 size, took 3sec instead of 98sec compare to first algorithm version):

```
class PrimeNumbers

  def initialize(size)
    raise ArgumentError if size < 2

    @array = 1.step(size,2).to_a
    @array.shift
    @prime = [2]
  end

  def process
    @array.each do |i|
      @prime.push(i) if inner_loop(i)
    end
    @prime
  end

  private

  def inner_loop(e, is_prime = true)
    3.step(e/3, 2) do |k|
      if e % k == 0
        is_prime = false
        break
      end
    end
    is_prime
  end

end
```

Depends on algorithm efficiency time results can be as following (original array 50000 size):

```
96.824695s (loop through all array)
92.385227s (loop through all array, skip even numbers in inner loop)
9.251714s  (loop through all array, skip even numbers in outer loop)
5.901579s  (loop through outer loop odds only)
3.480197s  (loop through outer loop odds only, cut half)
2.329469s  (loop through outer loop odds only, cut two thirds)
```

Why to cut half? Because 67/51 can not be Integer. Why to cut third? There is strong dependency. Look the delimiters for odd numbers:

[image]

**UPDATE**:

Diving deeper into algorithm I've find out that no need to loop through  half or even third size of initial array. At the end you can iterate through less than 10% of array to reject composite numbers.

It is relevantly easy to cut 1/2 or 1/3, but to cut 4/5 you have to exclude 9, to cut 7/8 - 9,15,25 etc. It helps to loop through only small set of data ignoring the rest of array. See more details on graph below:

[image]

```
0.398072s  (loop through odds only, cut selective block depend on initial size)
```

What selective block is? Let's choose Array size, for instance 8000 and see through the variables:

```
size          = 8000
@loop_end     = 19
@denominators = [9, 15, 21, 27, 33, 39, 45, 51, 25, 35, 45, 55, 65, 75, 85, 49, 63, 77, 91, 105, 119, 81, 99, 117, 135, 153, 121, 143, 165, 187, 169, 195, 221, 225, 255, 289]
```

> Maximum number of values you need to loop through is 5% (19/20)! So to compare a given value no need to loop more than first 5-10% of values.

For the algorithm it is enough to loop through 421 elements to select prime numbers. In case of bigger input @loop_end will adapt. On smaller data set (1000 values) the variables are:

```
size          = 1000
@loop_end     = 9
@denominators = [9, 15, 21, 25, 35, 49]
```

Loop through 111 elements helps to find out prime numbers from 1000 elements array. Although @denominators array is bigger than actual denominators (see spreadsheet above) but it doesn't affect correctness of the algorithm. We reject @denominators and loop up to **element/@loop_end** with step 2 to avoid even numbers.

The optimization to speed algorithm up 320x is really impressive. See the code down below:

```
class PrimeNumbers

  def initialize(size)
    raise ArgumentError if size < 2
    prepare_vars(size)
  end

  def process
    @array.each do |i|
      next if @denominators.include?(i)
      @prime.push(i) if test_of_prime(i)
    end
    @prime
  end

  private

  def prepare_vars(size)
    @prime = [2]
    @array = 1.step(size,2).to_a
    @array.shift

    @loop_end      = (size**(1/3.0)).to_i
    @loop_end     += 1 if (@loop_end % 2 == 0)
    @denominators  = []

    3.step(@loop_end-2,2).each do |i|
      i.step(@loop_end-2,2).each do |k|
        @denominators << i * k
      end
    end
  end

  def test_of_prime(e, is_prime = true)
    3.step(e/@loop_end, 2) do |k|
      if e % k == 0
        is_prime = false
        break
      end
    end
    is_prime
  end

end
```

Unit tests are available down below:

```
require 'minitest/autorun'

class PrimeNumbersTest < Minitest::Unit::TestCase

  def test_valid_1
    assert_equal [2], PrimeNumbers.new(2).process
  end

  def test_valid_2
    assert_equal [2, 3, 5, 7, 11], PrimeNumbers.new(11).process
  end

  def test_valid_3
    assert_equal [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47], PrimeNumbers.new(50).process
  end

  def test_valid_4
    assert_equal [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97], PrimeNumbers.new(100).process
  end

  def test_valid_5
    assert_equal [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103, 107, 109, 113, 127, 131, 137, 139, 149, 151, 157, 163, 167, 173, 179, 181, 191, 193, 197, 199, 211, 223, 227, 229, 233, 239, 241, 251, 257, 263, 269, 271, 277, 281, 283, 293, 307, 311, 313, 317, 331, 337, 347, 349, 353, 359, 367, 373, 379, 383, 389, 397, 401, 409, 419, 421, 431, 433, 439, 443, 449, 457, 461, 463, 467, 479, 487, 491, 499, 503, 509, 521, 523, 541, 547, 557, 563, 569, 571, 577, 587, 593, 599, 601, 607, 613, 617, 619, 631, 641, 643, 647, 653, 659, 661, 673, 677, 683, 691, 701, 709, 719, 727, 733, 739, 743, 751, 757, 761, 769, 773, 787, 797], PrimeNumbers.new(800).process
  end

  def test_valid_6
    assert_equal [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103, 107, 109, 113, 127, 131, 137, 139, 149, 151, 157, 163, 167, 173, 179, 181, 191, 193, 197, 199, 211, 223, 227, 229, 233, 239, 241, 251, 257, 263, 269, 271, 277, 281, 283, 293, 307, 311, 313, 317, 331, 337, 347, 349, 353, 359, 367, 373, 379, 383, 389, 397, 401, 409, 419, 421, 431, 433, 439, 443, 449, 457, 461, 463, 467, 479, 487, 491, 499, 503, 509, 521, 523, 541, 547, 557, 563, 569, 571, 577, 587, 593, 599, 601, 607, 613, 617, 619, 631, 641, 643, 647, 653, 659, 661, 673, 677, 683, 691, 701, 709, 719, 727, 733, 739, 743, 751, 757, 761, 769, 773, 787, 797, 809, 811, 821, 823, 827, 829, 839, 853, 857, 859, 863, 877, 881, 883, 887, 907, 911, 919, 929, 937, 941, 947, 953, 967, 971, 977, 983, 991, 997, 1009, 1013, 1019, 1021, 1031, 1033, 1039, 1049, 1051, 1061, 1063, 1069, 1087, 1091, 1093, 1097, 1103, 1109, 1117, 1123, 1129, 1151, 1153, 1163, 1171, 1181, 1187, 1193, 1201, 1213, 1217, 1223, 1229, 1231, 1237, 1249, 1259, 1277, 1279, 1283, 1289, 1291, 1297, 1301, 1303, 1307, 1319, 1321, 1327, 1361, 1367, 1373, 1381, 1399, 1409, 1423, 1427, 1429, 1433, 1439, 1447, 1451, 1453, 1459, 1471, 1481, 1483, 1487, 1489, 1493, 1499], PrimeNumbers.new(1500).process
  end

  def test_valid_7
    assert_equal [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103, 107, 109, 113, 127, 131, 137, 139, 149, 151, 157, 163, 167, 173, 179, 181, 191, 193, 197, 199, 211, 223, 227, 229, 233, 239, 241, 251, 257, 263, 269, 271, 277, 281, 283, 293, 307, 311, 313, 317, 331, 337, 347, 349, 353, 359, 367, 373, 379, 383, 389, 397, 401, 409, 419, 421, 431, 433, 439, 443, 449, 457, 461, 463, 467, 479, 487, 491, 499, 503, 509, 521, 523, 541, 547, 557, 563, 569, 571, 577, 587, 593, 599, 601, 607, 613, 617, 619, 631, 641, 643, 647, 653, 659, 661, 673, 677, 683, 691, 701, 709, 719, 727, 733, 739, 743, 751, 757, 761, 769, 773, 787, 797, 809, 811, 821, 823, 827, 829, 839, 853, 857, 859, 863, 877, 881, 883, 887, 907, 911, 919, 929, 937, 941, 947, 953, 967, 971, 977, 983, 991, 997, 1009, 1013, 1019, 1021, 1031, 1033, 1039, 1049, 1051, 1061, 1063, 1069, 1087, 1091, 1093, 1097, 1103, 1109, 1117, 1123, 1129, 1151, 1153, 1163, 1171, 1181, 1187, 1193, 1201, 1213, 1217, 1223, 1229, 1231, 1237, 1249, 1259, 1277, 1279, 1283, 1289, 1291, 1297, 1301, 1303, 1307, 1319, 1321, 1327, 1361, 1367, 1373, 1381, 1399, 1409, 1423, 1427, 1429, 1433, 1439, 1447, 1451, 1453, 1459, 1471, 1481, 1483, 1487, 1489, 1493, 1499, 1511, 1523, 1531, 1543, 1549, 1553, 1559, 1567, 1571, 1579, 1583, 1597, 1601, 1607, 1609, 1613, 1619, 1621, 1627, 1637, 1657, 1663, 1667, 1669, 1693, 1697, 1699, 1709, 1721, 1723, 1733, 1741, 1747, 1753, 1759, 1777, 1783, 1787, 1789, 1801, 1811, 1823, 1831, 1847, 1861, 1867, 1871, 1873, 1877, 1879, 1889, 1901, 1907, 1913, 1931, 1933, 1949, 1951, 1973, 1979, 1987, 1993, 1997, 1999, 2003, 2011, 2017, 2027, 2029, 2039, 2053, 2063, 2069, 2081, 2083, 2087, 2089, 2099, 2111, 2113, 2129, 2131, 2137, 2141, 2143, 2153, 2161, 2179, 2203, 2207, 2213, 2221, 2237, 2239, 2243, 2251, 2267, 2269, 2273, 2281, 2287, 2293, 2297, 2309, 2311, 2333, 2339, 2341, 2347, 2351, 2357, 2371, 2377, 2381, 2383, 2389, 2393, 2399, 2411, 2417, 2423, 2437, 2441, 2447, 2459, 2467, 2473, 2477, 2503, 2521, 2531, 2539, 2543, 2549, 2551, 2557, 2579, 2591, 2593, 2609, 2617, 2621, 2633, 2647, 2657, 2659, 2663, 2671, 2677, 2683, 2687, 2689, 2693, 2699, 2707, 2711, 2713, 2719, 2729, 2731, 2741, 2749, 2753, 2767, 2777, 2789, 2791, 2797, 2801, 2803, 2819, 2833, 2837, 2843, 2851, 2857, 2861, 2879, 2887, 2897, 2903, 2909, 2917, 2927, 2939, 2953, 2957, 2963, 2969, 2971, 2999, 3001, 3011, 3019, 3023, 3037, 3041, 3049, 3061, 3067, 3079, 3083, 3089, 3109, 3119, 3121, 3137, 3163, 3167, 3169, 3181, 3187, 3191, 3203, 3209, 3217, 3221, 3229, 3251, 3253, 3257, 3259, 3271, 3299, 3301, 3307, 3313, 3319, 3323, 3329, 3331, 3343, 3347, 3359, 3361, 3371, 3373, 3389, 3391, 3407, 3413, 3433, 3449, 3457, 3461, 3463, 3467, 3469, 3491, 3499, 3511, 3517, 3527, 3529, 3533, 3539, 3541, 3547, 3557, 3559, 3571, 3581, 3583, 3593, 3607, 3613, 3617, 3623, 3631, 3637, 3643, 3659, 3671, 3673, 3677, 3691, 3697, 3701, 3709, 3719, 3727, 3733, 3739, 3761, 3767, 3769, 3779, 3793, 3797, 3803, 3821, 3823, 3833, 3847, 3851, 3853, 3863, 3877, 3881, 3889, 3907, 3911, 3917, 3919, 3923, 3929, 3931, 3943, 3947, 3967, 3989, 4001, 4003, 4007, 4013, 4019, 4021, 4027, 4049, 4051, 4057, 4073, 4079, 4091, 4093, 4099, 4111, 4127, 4129, 4133, 4139, 4153, 4157, 4159, 4177, 4201, 4211, 4217, 4219, 4229, 4231, 4241, 4243, 4253, 4259, 4261, 4271, 4273, 4283, 4289, 4297, 4327, 4337, 4339, 4349, 4357, 4363, 4373, 4391, 4397, 4409, 4421, 4423, 4441, 4447, 4451, 4457, 4463, 4481, 4483, 4493, 4507, 4513, 4517, 4519, 4523, 4547, 4549, 4561, 4567, 4583, 4591, 4597, 4603, 4621, 4637, 4639, 4643, 4649, 4651, 4657, 4663, 4673, 4679, 4691, 4703, 4721, 4723, 4729, 4733, 4751, 4759, 4783, 4787, 4789, 4793, 4799, 4801, 4813, 4817, 4831, 4861, 4871, 4877, 4889, 4903, 4909, 4919, 4931, 4933, 4937, 4943, 4951, 4957, 4967, 4969, 4973, 4987, 4993, 4999, 5003, 5009, 5011, 5021, 5023, 5039, 5051, 5059, 5077, 5081, 5087, 5099, 5101, 5107, 5113, 5119, 5147, 5153, 5167, 5171, 5179, 5189, 5197, 5209, 5227, 5231, 5233, 5237, 5261, 5273, 5279, 5281, 5297, 5303, 5309, 5323, 5333, 5347, 5351, 5381, 5387, 5393, 5399, 5407, 5413, 5417, 5419, 5431, 5437, 5441, 5443, 5449, 5471, 5477, 5479, 5483, 5501, 5503, 5507, 5519, 5521, 5527, 5531, 5557, 5563, 5569, 5573, 5581, 5591, 5623, 5639, 5641, 5647, 5651, 5653, 5657, 5659, 5669, 5683, 5689, 5693, 5701, 5711, 5717, 5737, 5741, 5743, 5749, 5779, 5783, 5791, 5801, 5807, 5813, 5821, 5827, 5839, 5843, 5849, 5851, 5857, 5861, 5867, 5869, 5879, 5881, 5897, 5903, 5923, 5927, 5939, 5953, 5981, 5987, 6007, 6011, 6029, 6037, 6043, 6047, 6053, 6067, 6073, 6079, 6089, 6091, 6101, 6113, 6121, 6131, 6133, 6143, 6151, 6163, 6173, 6197, 6199, 6203, 6211, 6217, 6221, 6229, 6247, 6257, 6263, 6269, 6271, 6277, 6287, 6299, 6301, 6311, 6317, 6323, 6329, 6337, 6343, 6353, 6359, 6361, 6367, 6373, 6379, 6389, 6397, 6421, 6427, 6449, 6451, 6469, 6473, 6481, 6491, 6521, 6529, 6547, 6551, 6553, 6563, 6569, 6571, 6577, 6581, 6599, 6607, 6619, 6637, 6653, 6659, 6661, 6673, 6679, 6689, 6691, 6701, 6703, 6709, 6719, 6733, 6737, 6761, 6763, 6779, 6781, 6791, 6793, 6803, 6823, 6827, 6829, 6833, 6841, 6857, 6863, 6869, 6871, 6883, 6899, 6907, 6911, 6917, 6947, 6949, 6959, 6961, 6967, 6971, 6977, 6983, 6991, 6997, 7001, 7013, 7019, 7027, 7039, 7043, 7057, 7069, 7079, 7103, 7109, 7121, 7127, 7129, 7151, 7159, 7177, 7187, 7193, 7207, 7211, 7213, 7219, 7229, 7237, 7243, 7247, 7253, 7283, 7297, 7307, 7309, 7321, 7331, 7333, 7349, 7351, 7369, 7393, 7411, 7417, 7433, 7451, 7457, 7459, 7477, 7481, 7487, 7489, 7499, 7507, 7517, 7523, 7529, 7537, 7541, 7547, 7549, 7559, 7561, 7573, 7577, 7583, 7589, 7591, 7603, 7607, 7621, 7639, 7643, 7649, 7669, 7673, 7681, 7687, 7691, 7699, 7703, 7717, 7723, 7727, 7741, 7753, 7757, 7759, 7789, 7793, 7817, 7823, 7829, 7841, 7853, 7867, 7873, 7877, 7879, 7883, 7901, 7907, 7919, 7927, 7933, 7937, 7949, 7951, 7963, 7993], PrimeNumbers.new(8000).process
  end

  def test_invalid_8
    assert_raises( ArgumentError ) { PrimeNumbers.new(1) }
  end

end
```

**UPDATE2**

Sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm is a way faster.

Comment: I wonder whether you would get even faster results if you were to use the primes you've already found as the possible denominators of futures primes.

Comment: @JonathonJones try please, I'm really interested to see the result.

Comment: @JonathonJones I tried it. To consider primes as denominators works but slower. 1.792194s against 0.535394s on 50000 array.

Comment: Very elaborate write up :). I'm not sure if you've used this fact, but it's actually proven mathematically that all of number's divisiors are contained in 1..sqrt(n). So it's enough to check divisiors until the square root of n, and if there are none, the number is prime.

Comment: @Anatoly thank you for running those tests, that certainly satisfies my curiosity, although now I want to know why it is so much faster. I guess the way you are creating the denominators must generate a shorter list than the list of previously found primes?

Comment: @JonathonJones we can profile the *Sieve of Eratosthenes* to compare with method described above and identify where the bottleneck is, please try and I update my answers with results

Answer (score 0):

You initialized `i` outside your loop, so subsequent numbers start by testing with an `i` already set to some high value.