# How to create a method that returns the nth prime number?

Tags: ruby, primes

I'm trying to write a method that returns the nth prime number.

I've worked out a solution but the problem is in my method. I create a large array of numbers that seems to process super slow. `(1..104729).to_a` to be exact. I chose 104729 because the max `n` can be is 10000 and the 10000th integer is 104729. I'm looking for a way to optimize my method.

Is 104729 is too large a value? Is there a way to write this so that I'm not creating a large array?

Here's the method:

```
def PrimeMover(num)

  def is_prime(x)
    i = 0
    nums = (2..x).to_a
    while nums[i] < nums.max
      if x % nums[i] != 0
        i += 1
      else
        return false
      end
    end
    return true
  end

  primes_arr = (3..104729).to_a.select {|y| is_prime(y)}

  primes_arr[num]

end
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I generate the first n prime numbers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11673968/how-do-i-generate-the-first-n-prime-numbers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Ruby's [built in `#prime?` method](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/prime/rdoc/Prime.html#method-i-prime-3F), which seems pretty efficient.

The code:

```
require 'prime'
primes_arr = (3..104729).to_a.select &:prime?
```

runs in 2-3 seconds on my machine, which I find somewhat acceptable.

If you need even better performance or if you really need to write your own method, try implementing the [Sieve of Erathostenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes). Here are some Ruby samples of that: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#Ruby

Comment: Wow. It took me forever to create that prime method. So `require 'prime'` calls the prime method? and is `select &:prime?` another way of writing `.select{|x| x.prime?}`

Comment: @user3640511: No, the `require` statement simply defines the needed class so you can use it; there are lots of classes in the standard library which aren't available without requiring them. And yes, `select(&:prime?)` is shorthand for `select{|x| x.prime?}`.

Comment: No. Method calls look like this: `expr.meth(args)` or `expr.meth args` which calls method `meth` on the object returned by evaluating the expression `expr` passing `args` as the argument. You can leave off the receiver, in which case it is implied to be `self`, this looks like this: `meth(args)` or `meth args`. So, `require 'prime'` calls the `require` method, passing the string literal `'prime'` as an argument. `require` loads a Ruby script or interpreter extension from the `$LOAD_PATH`, in this case, it loads a file from the Ruby standard library.

Answer (score 10):

```
require "prime"

def find_prime(nth)
  Prime.take(nth).last
end
```

Comment: This should be the selected answer.

Answer (score 5):

Combine Ruby's built-in [prime library](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/prime/rdoc/Prime.html), and a [lazy enumerator](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerator/Lazy.html) for performance:

```
require 'prime'
(1...100_000).lazy.select(&:prime?).take(100).to_a
```

Or simply, as highlighted by Arturo:

```
Prime.take(100)
```

Comment: Thank you! I don't exactly understand enumerators and haven't seen the lazy or take method. Will look into it now. Appreciate the help.

Comment: Using `lazy` is very useful when dealing with large ranges. Exploding a range into an array can consume a LOT of memory and take a machine to its knees, whereas using `lazy` helps avoids that.

Answer (score 1):

Here's <strike>an optimal</strike> a trial division implementation of `is_prime` without relying on the `Prime` class:

A prime number is a whole number divisible only by 1 and itself, and 1 is not prime. So we want to know if `x` divides into anything less than x and greater than 1. So we start the count at `2`, and we end at `x - 1`.

```
def prime?(x)
  return false if x < 2
  2.upto(x - 1) do |n|
    return false if (x % n).zero?
  end
  true
end
```

As soon as `x % n` has a remainder, we can break the loop and say this number is not prime. This saves you from looping over the entire range. If all the possible numbers were exhausted, we know the number is prime.

This is still not optimal. For that you would need a [sieve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes), or a different detection algorithm to trial division. But it's a big improvement on your code. Taking the nth up to you.

Comment: Thumbs up for the effort, but note that `prime` is not an external library, but rather built-in stdlib that simply doesn't load by default.

Comment: @BorisStitnicky ahh, thanks for pointing that out. I thought it was not part of stdlib.

Comment: Nice, but definitely not optimal. You're doing trial division by far too many numbers.

Comment: @DanaJ yeah, I've spent the past couple of days researching this, and now I definitely know this is the case. Optimal would involve sieves for example, or some other scheme that's not trial devision. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

Comment: It's an interesting problem.  I don't think "optimal" is possible without restricting the algorithm (e.g. optimal trial division) or input range, and it's dubious even then.  Trial division is good for very small inputs, using primes (or at worst 2 then odds) to the square root of n.  At some point deterministic M-R tests, then perhaps BPSW.  Crossovers dependent on implementation and platform.  Other possibilities for very small inputs are lookup in a pre-sieved bit array or binary search in an array of small primes.